# Mathematica 10 installs but won't start on Windows 7

Tags: version-10, crash, installation

I've installed Mathematica 10.4 on my laptop and it loads and runs without any trouble.  On my desktop, however, it seems to install fine, but then when I first launch Mathematica.exe (or WolframKernel.exe or MathKernel.exe directly) I get the message that "Wolfram Kernel for Windows has stopped working" at the "Initializing internal preferences..." stage.  More details:

```
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   WolframKernel.exe
Fault Module Name:  WolframEngine.DLL
Exception Code:     c000001d
Exception Offset:   0000000001299213
```

Once I kill that, the start-up just hangs until I click on it, then it crashes too.  Mathematica 9 works fine on this desktop, but I tried installing 10.3 and it has the same behavior and "WolframEngine.DLL" is always at fault.

My guess is that there is some incompatibility with something on this computer and Mathematica 10.X, but the Windows7 OS and most of the software installed on both computers is basically identical.  Or maybe it's a setting.  Or (and I'm really stretching it here) maybe it's because this is Japanese hardware with a U.S. OS and Mathematica is doing some check on drivers.

Anybody with some experience or insight on the problem?

Comment: I believe you should contact the support desk... We're just _Mathematica_ users after all.

Comment: Check the exact version of your OS, if it's build 7600 (the original Windows 7 release) you will need to upgrade to at least SP1.

Comment: Hey ilian, that was actually the problem, SP1 hadn't been installed on this desktop, but now it's working fine.  Post as the answer and I'll give you credit for solving my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a problem with Windows 7 build 7600 (the original Windows 7 release).

More information can be found [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/981479) or [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/811093/visual-studio-2013-rtm-c-x64-code-generation-bug-for-avx2-instructions), but in a nutshell, the processor supports AVX/FMA3 instructions, while the operating system does not. This is misdetected by the Visual Studio 2013 C Runtime math library which tries to use them anyway, resulting in an "illegal instruction" exception.

The recommended solution is to upgrade Windows 7 to at least Service Pack 1 (build 7601) which should enable AVX support.